# Does a successful LTSC repair reinstall reboot to desktop/login? Evidence in Logs?

Tags: windows, windows-10, reinstall

Left PC to reinstall LTSC, in-place Windows repair reinstall started from Windows LTSC, went to bed as I saw it restarting and installing. 
On return it just showed the desktop, with audio driver now missing.

I was expecting a setup window. Is reinstall, reboot to desktop/login screen (I already had auto-login) expected behaviour, or did it fail?

Are there other indicators, what logs can I check, or otherwise to, confirm whether this was a succesful repair reinstall?

Comment: If you started the install from within Windows, basically did an in-place upgrade to the same version, you have not provide enough information to identify if the installation failed.  Have you check the logs that were generated by the upgrade/install?

Comment: Apols, I've edited for clarity. Yes, in-place, in Windows repair install. I've looked through logs but I can't find what I need, and don't know what to look for.

Comment: You don't indicate what LTSC version you are installing.  It's also not clear if you have attempted to install the drivers yourself for your audio device.

Comment: Version: 10.0.17763 Build 17763, from ISO SW_DVD5_WIN_ENT_LTSC_2019_64-bit_English_MLF_X21-96425.iso

I reinstalled the audio driver, now working again.

If you could tell me what to look for in LOGS, that would resolve this. Thanks